# TornadoFX ItemViewModel updating if backing object that do not expose JavaFX properties is changed

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I have a following code

```
class MainView : View("Example") {
    val model: UserModel = UserModel()

    init {
        model.item = User(status = true)
    }

    override val root = vbox {
        useMaxWidth = true
        label(model.status)
        button("Get new status") {
            action {
                model.item.updateStatus()
                println("Status in model: ${model.status.value}")
                println("Status in backing object: ${model.item.status}")
            }
        }
    }
}

class User(var status: Boolean, val api: Api = Api()) {

    fun updateStatus() {
        status = api.getStatus()
    }
}


class UserModel : ItemViewModel<User>() {
    val status = bind(User::status)
}


class Api {
    fun getStatus(): Boolean {
        val list = listOf(true, false)
        return list[(Math.random() * list.size).toInt()]
    }
}
```

After clicking the button the `model.itemProperty` changes but the `model.status` doesn't. Calling `model.rollback()` does the trick but I suppose it is not the proper way to get the `ItemViewModel` updated after backing property is changed. Is there any TornadoFX's way to update `UserModel` (and corresponding View as a result) without assigning a new `User` object to the `model.item`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your backing object is not observable, calling `rollback()` is exactly the right thing to do. The semantics fit your use case perfectly, as rollback makes sure your `ViewModel` matches the values in the already assigned backing object.

In your case, you know what's changed so if you want to keep the existing values as they are and only update the status you might as well be pragmatic about it:

```
model.status.value = model.item.status
```

Personally, I always use observable values when I can, they don't add much boilerplate with the new syntax, and they enable you to write your code in a much more declarative way. For completeness, this is how you'd declare the `status` as an observable property in `User`:

```
val statusProperty = SimpleBooleanProperty()
var status by statusProperty
```